# process kill method not working

Tags: c#, process

I have a C# code and it checks for Winword instance and if there are more then 1 I use `process.kill` method to kill other process with `winword` process name.

It seems the `process.kill` is not able to kill the `winword`. Can you please help? As of now we have to reboot the server in order to kill other `winword` instances.

Comment: Any errors? Application has permission to kill the process / winword? The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the Kill method, call the WaitForExit method to wait for the process to exit, or check the HasExited property to determine if the process has exited.

Comment: How are you selecting the word process ? what code are you using to select and kill? what version of word, what version of windows?

Comment: Can you show your code ?

Comment: Please post your existing code with your question

Answer (score 2):

This method should work

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("winword"))
{
    try
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { };
}
```

Capitals shouldn't matter but you could try killing "WINWORD" or "WINWORD.EXE"

Comment: I would add a try-catch inside the loop just to be sure. Maybe the process is elevated.

Comment: Same code I am using as you mention. I tried killing the word myself but can't do. Only Rebooting the server is working.

Comment: @BugFinder I am using windows 2003 and ms office 2007

Comment: @Muralidharan  Not able to find waitforexit method. I am using vs2010. Will this method wait forever if it is not able to kill.

Comment: What I observed that when i open ms word it create new process with winword.exe and when I close it, process explorere still shows the winword.exe in task manager, whereas it should have killed that process.

Comment: @akhilPatel can you kill the proces from task manager? If so. Copy that exact name to your code. And post your excact code and not keywords of it. And post what `Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")` returns

Comment: It just so happened that I needed this solution as well for Excel. Youri Leenman your solution worked great! Here's how I implemented it:`System.Diagnostics.Process[] allExcel;
                allExcel = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
                for (int i = 0; i < allExcel.Length; i++) {
                    allExcel[i].CloseMainWindow();
                }`

Comment: @YouriLeenman When i kill process from task manager it says task end but i can still see the process in task manager

Comment: @akhilPatel then the process doesn't get killed indeed. You should solve this problem first. Find out why the process doesn't get killed